# C# SQLiteDataAdapter Removing Forwardslash

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I am trying to read from an Sqlite database in to a DataTable using SQLiteDataAdapter. The data in the database contains forwardslashes in fractions being stored as VARCHAR data types. After filling the DataTable, the forwardslashes have been removed along with all trailing characters. I have confirmed the database does contain the forwardslashes.

This is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connection))
{
    string sql = "Select Quantity From Recipes WHERE ID=@id;";
    using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, m_dbConnection))
    {
        da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id") { Value = ID });
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

The result in Quantity should return 1/2, but returns 1 instead. This is different than the problem most posts refer to where people are trying to insert forwardslashes. I couldn't find any information about reading forwardslashes.

Comment: That's a forward slash, not a backslash ;)

Comment: Oops...fixed my post. Thanks.

Comment: there's some fancy string to int conversion going on somewhere - is your sqlite field type for quantity marked as an int? are you sure it's a varchar? What do you get if the data is 12/3 ?

Comment: I found my mistake. I create the table programmatically in C# and had changed it to create Quantity as a VARCHAR, but had never dropped the original table which was still using a REAL. So I kept assuming it was a VARCHAR when it had not been changed yet. Thanks for your help.